# Iphone Simulator terminating opening a new Table ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

In my application I had a button and from there I opened a `TableViewController` and it worked perfectly fine.

And now I added another button and I linked the button to another `TableViewController`

[image]

Now when I am clicking this new button my application is crashing:

`libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException`

In other places in StackOverflow they mentioned about an unclosed `IBOutlet` but I have not created any outlet for the button itself, so what problem could that be.

Log :

```
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010712f34b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010677321e objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107198265 +[NSException raise:format:] + 197
    3   UIKit                               0x000000010797383c -[UITableViewController loadView] + 638
    4   UIKit                               0x00000001076f3c4c -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 201
    5   UIKit                               0x00000001076f44a0 -[UIViewController view] + 27
    6   UIKit                               0x0000000107fb88d0 -[_UIFullscreenPresentationController _setPresentedViewController:] + 87
    7   UIKit                               0x00000001076ced26 -[UIPresentationController initWithPresentedViewController:presentingViewController:] + 141
    8   UIKit                               0x000000010770730b -[UIViewController _presentViewController:withAnimationController:completion:] + 3956
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010770a6df -[UIViewController _performCoordinatedPresentOrDismiss:animated:] + 530
    10  UIKit                               0x000000010770a1c5 -[UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:] + 179
    11  UIKit                               0x000000010770f892 -[UIViewController _showViewController:withAction:sender:] + 274
    12  UIKit                               0x0000000107bd41b6 __66-[UIStoryboardShowSegueTemplate newDefaultPerformHandlerForSegue:]_block_invoke + 134
    13  UIKit                               0x0000000107d2d40d -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate _performWithDestinationViewController:sender:] + 447
    14  UIKit                               0x0000000107d2d21d -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate _perform:] + 82
    15  UIKit                               0x0000000107d2d4df -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate perform:] + 156
    16  UIKit                               0x0000000107554b88 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 83
    17  UIKit                               0x00000001076da2b2 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
    18  UIKit                               0x00000001076da5cb -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 444
    19  UIKit                               0x00000001076d94c7 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 668
    20  UIKit                               0x00000001075c20d5 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 2747
    21  UIKit                               0x00000001075c37c3 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 4011
    22  UIKit                               0x0000000107570a33 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 371
    23  UIKit                               0x0000000107d62b6d __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 3248
    24  UIKit                               0x0000000107d5b817 __handleEventQueue + 4879
    25  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001070d4311 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    26  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001070b959c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
    27  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001070b8a86 __CFRunLoopRun + 918
    28  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001070b8494 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
    29  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000109ebaa6f GSEventRunModal + 161
    30  UIKit                               0x0000000107552f34 UIApplicationMain + 159
    31  OneTest                             0x0000000105bfbc3f main + 111
    32  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000108eef68d start + 1
)
```

This is what I did, I removed that new TableViewcontroller. Then I added a new ViewController and linked this ViewController to my Button by making a Segue. To the same button and it worked by opening the new ViewController. Then as soon as I linked the new View controller to my class it stopped working. Any possible reason for that?

Comment: There should be some other message that tells you why the exception was thrown

Comment: You should disable any breakpoints if you have. Then, you should see a complete error message just like Paulw11 said. Please post that message.

Comment: @NeilAppleDeveloper I have disabled the breakpoints, the log message of error I have already posted. What could be the possible reason?

Comment: Based on the call stack, when the table calls loadView it crashes. Normally, Xcode will give you a longer and more specific error message. Please check the delegate and data source of the table. There are certain delegate methods that you have to implement.

Comment: @NeilAppleDeveloper This is what I did, I removed that new TableViewcontroller. Then I added a new ViewController and linked this ViewController to my Button by making a Segue. To the same button and it worked by opening the new ViewController.

Then as soon as I linked the new View controller to my class it stopped working.

Any possible reason for that?

Comment: @Paulw11 Check my above comment. Does that give any info for the possible error?

Comment: @arqam, Did you copy paste the previously designed button to take the new button. If so check the connection of that button, both button might have same connection and results the crash. Check and let me know.

Comment: @Janmenjaya I didn't copy paste. Both buttons have different triggered segues. It works fine the moment till I define my TableViewController class as the Custom Class for the view.

Comment: Have you tagged `Display..` method as an `IBAction`?